# Making sorbet with fruit frozen before processing

Tags: strawberries, sorbet

I've accidentally frozen a bunch of good strawberries with the leaves still on. I want to make them into sorbet. I don't plan to cook the berries. Should I:

1. Thaw the berries, cut the tops off, puree, make sorbet?
2. Try to cut the tops off the berries while still frozen, puree, make sorbet?
3. Leave the tops on, puree, make sorbet?
4. Some other procedure?

Comment: Thaw, remove the tops, ...

Comment: In my experience the tops won't hurt the flavour of your sorbet.  The only downside is that you might have some green flecks in your final product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thaw just enough to easily remove the tops and cut into halves or quarters, then puree while still semi-frozen. That will give you a head start on the chilling of the sorbet mixture. You want that super cold anyway, before you put it into the machine.